# Command Binding in WPF

Tags: c#

I'm trying to learn Command Binding but with my first code I have an error.I searched a lot for resolve my problem but I wasn't successful.
This is my XML Code :

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" 
    x:Class="Office.Windows.winMain"
    xmlns:local = "clr-namespace:Office"
    Closing="Window_Closing"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="Window_Loaded" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized"
    Title="Main Window" Height="459.593" Width="604.36">

<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="local:CustomCommands.Exit" CanExecute="ExitCommand_CanExecute" Executed="ExitCommand_Executed" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Grid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

And this is my code behind

```
public partial class winMain : Window
{
    public winMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static class CustomCommands
    {
        public static readonly RoutedUICommand Exit = new RoutedUICommand
            (
                "Exit",
                "Exit",
                typeof(CustomCommands),
                new InputGestureCollection()
                {
                new KeyGesture(Key.End, ModifierKeys.Control)
                }
            );
    }
    private void ExitCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
     {
            e.CanExecute = true;
     }

     private void ExitCommand_Executed(object sender,ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
     {
          Application.Current.Shutdown();
     }
   }
}
```

But in this code I have the error *The name "CustomCommands" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Office".* And also I have to say my MainWindow is in Windows Folder in my project but I tried both namespace *clr-namespace:Office* and *clr-namespace:Office.Windows*. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Your `CustomCommands` class is defined inside your WinMain class. I suggest moving it to the top level in the namespace, and then using the namespace `Office.Windows`, if that is the namespace in which you put the class.

If you wish to keep it as it is, use `clr-namespace:Office.Windows` and then reference `winMain.CustomCommands.Exit`, as that is, where the commands currently reside.

Comment: Thanks a lot.But still I have problem.when my window lost focus the command dose not working.Is there any way to have access to my command in all of my project?

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883004/wpf-commandbindings-defined-in-one-window-not-available-in-another

Comment: Yes something like this but I don't want to write my command binding in all of my window.Is there any way to have access the command that is in Main Window???

Comment: Read the answers to the other question, specifically this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/52023930/2451871 :-)